# SQL dbase Remove String

Tags: sql, twitter

I am doing a Twitter project and at the beginning of some Tweets because they are retweets I have the two letters RT (Retweets). I am wondering how can I delete these RT letters from all the Tweets that have them. I tried to use this SQL command but it doesn't work.

UPDATE Twitter SET Tweet = REPLACE(REPLACE(Tweet, 'RT', ''), 'RT', '')
WHERE Tweet LIKE '%RT'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your text says the *beginning* of the string, yet your search pattern is at the end.  You could, conceivable try:

```
UPDATE Twitter
    SET Tweet = REPLACE(Tweet, 'RT', '')
    WHERE Tweet LIKE 'RT%';
```

However, the rest of the string might contain `'RT'` in it, so that is dangerous.  You can try something like this instead:

```
UPDATE Twitter
    SET Tweet = right(Tweet, len(Tweet) - 2)
    WHERE Tweet LIKE 'RT%';
```

In some databases, the `len()` function is spelled `length()`.  Some databases don't support `right()`, so you would need to use that database's substring function.